# Node.js and Express why my server is getting async became corrupt error when I receive more than one request in short period of time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, express, asynchronous

Using Node.js V9.2.0 and Express.js V4.16.3.

Using Node.js clusters (4):

```
Master cluster setting up 4 workers...
Worker 2138 is online
Worker 2140 is online
Worker 2141 is online
Worker 2139 is online
Connected and listening on port 3000
Connected and listening on port 3000
Connected and listening on port 3000
Connected and listening on port 3000
```

When I send a signle HTTP request from the GUI to the server everything is okay. 2 Are also fine. But 5 concurrent requests makes the following error:

```
Error: async hook stack has become corrupted (actual: 495, expected: 512)
 1: node::AsyncWrap::PopAsyncIds(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x126e479842fd
Worker 2141 stopped with code: 1, and signal: null
Starting a new worker
Worker 2146 is online
Connected and listening on port 3000
```

Is this something that should be defined in Express or Node config in order to prevent this from happening?

In addition - I wonder - if I receive only 5 concurrent requests from regular users of my app, the server will be shut down?

What am I missing?

Comment: Try updating to the newest Node, if the error still occurs fill out a bugreport. Nodejs should never crash on that level. Also have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13906)

Comment: Those requests are from the same computer & IP and they were made using a `for` loop of n5. Is this matters?

Comment: @JonasWilms Im not using any kind of code of `async_hooks`

Comment: In every request (unless there's no valid token) there is a call or even multiple calls to the MongoDB. If I have 4 clusters that means I can serve for only 4 customers at a time? Or If each customer asks for 4 multiple resources at one time I can serve for only one customer at a time? Anyone please answer.

Comment: No, rather 4000 if done right